# Capturing onclick on fast changing view

Tags: android, click, capture

I got parentView  and many childViews [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MOAJ.png)
I want to capture onClick event on childView. All childViews refresh about 30 times per second (by removing view creating new and putting it again). Standard method like setting onClick listener doesn't work because before onClick is set the view is removed.
I managed to capture onTouch event by onInterceptTouchEvent on childView and then i match position of child and position of MotionEvent that I receive.
Is there any more reliable and efficient way to do this?

Comment: whatever you're describing, it's just bad UI. you shouldn't remove and create views all the time

Comment: I would say that updating views 30 times por second is overkill.   Your user will not appreciate this.  12.5 Frames are enough for animations (especially  small ones )to look fluent.   You may consider to tell us more about your application